# find an altered image from the original image data set

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Here is my problem:

I must match two images. One image from the project folder and this folder have over 20.000 images. The other one is from a camera.

What I have done?

I can compare images with basic OpenCV example codes that I found in the documentation. [OpenCV Doc](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/d27/tutorial_py_table_of_contents_feature2d.html) I can also compare and find an image by using the hash of my image data set. It is so fast and it is only suitable for 2 exact images. One for query the other one is the target. But they are the same exact image.

So, I need something as reliable as feature matching and as fast as hash methods. But I can't use machine learning or anything on that level. It should be basic. Plus, I'm new to these stuff. So, my term project is on risk.

Example scenario:

If I ever take a picture of an image in my image data set from my computer's screen. This would change many features of the original image. In the case of defining what's in that image, a human won't struggle much but a comparison algorithm will struggle. Such a case leaves lot's of basic comparison algorithm out of the game. But, a machine-learning algorithm could solve the problem but it's forbidden to use in my project.

Needs:

It must be fast.

It must be accurate.

It must be easy to understand.

Any help is okay. A piece of code, maybe an article or a tutorial. Even an advice or a topic title might be really helpful to me.

Comment: do your changes preserve the image metadata? what exactly did you do? provide examples.

Comment: @piglet all i was trying to say is, i took a picture and use it as my query in my image set. Hence, each time i take a picture of an object it should be a little different right? So, this is my issue. I know i have the object in the image set but it is not the same on pixel level. Can i solve this problem without machine learning or any high level object detection algorithm?

Comment: that would depend on the object and its environment. but in most scenarios no.

Comment: Your first and third paragraphs add nothing to the question and the middle paragraph doesn't really make sense. Could you clarify what the question is please, thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell is it better now? I'm so lost and afraid. That's why I can't even describe.

Answer (score 0):

Once saw this camera model identification challenge on kaggle. [This notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/zeemeen/i-have-a-clue-what-i-am-doing-noise-patterns) discusses about noise pattern changes with changing devices. May be you should look in to this and other notebooks in that challenge. Thanks!

Comment: I'll check this as soon as possible!

Comment: I've checked the notebook but I'm afraid I should say, this is not the thing I want to achieve or overcome. I've updated my question maybe after reading that you may understand my issue much better. Thanks